# Matplotlib cannot switch backend to 'TkAgg', as 'qt' is currently running

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am trying to display a plot in Pycharm Comunity Edition and I get the following error:

> UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so >cannot show the figure.

I have installed and imported `tkinter` before importing `matplotlib` but I cannot make Matplotlib switch to  'TKAgg'.

I tried running

```
matplotlib.use('TKAgg', force=True)
```

and

```
plt.switch_backend('tkagg')
```

and they both result in the following error:

> ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive >framework, as 'qt' is currently running

I also tried adding MPLBACKEND=TkAgg to the environment variables but did not change anything.

Does anyone have an idea what else I can do to solve this so that I can display graphs?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I somehow got it to work by putting the

```
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
```

statement at the end of my module imports.

Essentially, the call to TkAgg was the last thing prior to the code. Not sure how it worked, but it worked for me. I think another module I was originally importing after the TkAgg statement was the issue.

I have tried putting the TkAgg statement back early in the module imports, and the issue comes back. When it is the last thing listed before my code starts, it works fine.